# browser "default" options "ask me" option

Tags: browser, default

I use more than one browser (4). Is it possible to have a right click option to select the browser I want to use to open links, that would allow the default to continue with normal click? Is there a Gnome extension that would do this? (I have not found one) Or any other way I could get this function?
Thanks this maybe an obscure request but more and more people are starting to use multiple browsers and may need this kind of function.

Comment: I don't have an answer for you, but there's an "Open With" extension for Thunderbird that I use and it lets me right click and open emailed links with the browser of my choosing.

Comment: Hadn't thought about going through Thunderbird, thanks will check it out!

Comment: It's a start. I don't think you'll be able to do it system wide, all with one elegant change. So, you can do the email aspect with that extension.

Answer (score 0):

Kinda hackish solution:

Create a keyboard shortcut for every browser with the command:

```
xdg-settings set default-web-browser <browser-here>.desktop
```

Every time you want to open a link with a specific browser, press the appropriate shortcut. Done.